# Understanding Cursor For Loop statements

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop, plsql, cursor

I have been searching for some answers on how to get a function like this working. To be honest, the information I've found has a minimum level of understanding that is clearly beyond mine, and I'm hoping someone can help me understand.

I have a query that returns multiple concatenated rows:

```
select
           V_FEEDBACK_FORM.TEAM_ID, MANAGER_USER, listagg(REF_NUMBER, '</ br>') within group (order by REF_NUMBER) as "REF_NUMBER"
        from
           V_FEEDBACK_FORM
        left join
           (select distinct TEAM_ID, MANAGER_USER from V_AUTH_INFO) "V_AUTH_INFO" on V_FEEDBACK_FORM.TEAM_ID = V_AUTH_INFO.TEAM_ID
        where
           trunc(UPDATED_ON) < trunc(SYSDATE) - 7
        group by
           V_FEEDBACK_FORM.TEAM_ID, MANAGER_USER;
```

And I trying to write a loop that searches through these results, selects the result of "TEAM_ID" and e-mails the relevant manager the concatenated string.

If anyone can help point me in the direct I need to be looking in, I do believe it's a Cursor For Loop but I just don't understand how to build that query, and I have been reading everything online for several hours now.

Cheers.

Comment: Not clear what do yo uneed but if you are looking `For Loop` usage then read this link https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1536

Comment: Also from where you get the manager email id, This is missing from your question

Comment: I'll have a look into that link, thank you very much.

The e-mail I can pull from somewhere else. I was unclear on that, so I do apologise. All I need is a loop to run, pull the results per row and run a procedure, per row. And close when there are no rows returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually prefer implicit cursor loops unless there's a need to use explicit cursors - they're efficient and the syntax is easy.

```
begin
  for r in 
  (select
       V_FEEDBACK_FORM.TEAM_ID, MANAGER_USER, 
       listagg(REF_NUMBER, '</ br>') within group (order by REF_NUMBER) as "REF_NUMBER"
    from V_FEEDBACK_FORM
    left join
       (select distinct TEAM_ID, MANAGER_USER from V_AUTH_INFO) "V_AUTH_INFO" on V_FEEDBACK_FORM.TEAM_ID = V_AUTH_INFO.TEAM_ID
    where trunc(UPDATED_ON) < trunc(SYSDATE) - 7
    group by V_FEEDBACK_FORM.TEAM_ID, MANAGER_USER)
  )
  loop
    -- put your code here to send an email for each row
    dbms_output.put_line(r.manager_user);
    dbms_output.put_line(r.team_id || ' ' || r."REF_NUMBER");
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Oh, and if you haven't sent emails before, I think people usually start with [UTL_SMTP](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_smtp.htm#ARPLS71478) and write their own simple "send_email" procedures. Let us know if you need help with that.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Not only that, it's simple and easy enough for me to understand, so thank you very much :)